# Add rows to table after each search in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, loops

Here is my model invoice.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class invoice extends CI_Model{

     function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function search($keyword){
        $this->db->like('code',$keyword);
        $query = $this->db->get('products');
        return $query->result();
    }
}
```

and my controller search.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class search extends CI_Controller{

    function __construct(){  
        parent:: __construct();  
        $this->load->model('frontend/invoice');  
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url','html'));
    }  

    public function index(){
        $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
        $data['results'] = $this->invoice->search($keyword);
        $this->load->view('header');  
        $this->load->view('frontend/navafterlogin');
        $this->load->view('frontend/dashboard');
        $this->load->view('frontend/results_view',$data);
        //$this->load->view('frontend/invoicetable');
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }

}
```

and a view to echo the searched result results_view.php

```
<table>
<?php
foreach($results as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" value="<?php echo $row->name?>"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" id="rate" value="<?php echo $row->perunitprice?>"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="quantity"value="" placeholder="quantity"/></td>
        <td><input type="number" id="result" value="" placeholder="total"/></td>
    </tr>
<?php   
}
?>
</table>
```

and my form from where I search dashboard.php

```
<div class="row">
       <?php echo form_open('frontend/search');?>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="keyword" placeholder="productcode">
            </div>

        <div class="col-sm-2">
             <button class="btn btn-warning">Find</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

What i want is every time when i perform search, i want to add new row on my  table which is results_view in this case and echo out the results in the separate rows.Currently i can search only once and on the second search, the first result gets replaced by second one and I don't want it to happen

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried using "Session", if did not, try this out in your controller index function :

```
public function index(){
     $this->load->library('session');
     $keyword = $this->input->post('keyword');
     $result = $this->invoice->search($keyword);
     $search = $this->session->userdata('search') ? (array)$this->session->userdata('search') : array();
     array_push($search, $result);
     $this->session->set_userdata('search', $search);
     $data['results'] = $search;

     $this->load->view('header');  
     $this->load->view('frontend/navafterlogin');
     $this->load->view('frontend/dashboard');
     $this->load->view('frontend/results_view',$data);
     //$this->load->view('frontend/invoicetable');
     $this->load->view('footer');
}
```